# Perforce integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am new to Perforce and Jenkins. I need to integrate perforce with Jenkins to automate the build process and build need to run based on changelist,
kindly suggest how to proceed

NOTE: Jenkins  running in windows and perforce server running in Linux

Thanks,
Sampath A

Comment: If you search for "perforce jenkins", you'll find that there's a plugin for Jenkins. If you are having _specific_ problems with setting this up, then you can update your question with details.

Comment: This is question is too open for stackoverflow, the site is more about helping to solve very specific technical problems. But it is not meant to provide How-tos. So try ! and if something does not work, provide an accurate description of what is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the update,perforce plugin integrated with Jenkins succesfully after that Workspace behaviour configured as
workspace name D:\539707\localbuild\DevBranches\BETA\UCB102\bms102
View Mappings //depot/DevBranches/BETA/UCB102/bms/... //D:\539707\localbuild\DevBranches\BETA\UCB102\bms102\...
while triggered the build getting below exception.
P4: Unable to setup workspace: com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException: Error in client specification.
Mapping '//D:\539707\localbuild\DevBranches\BETA\UCB102\bms102\...' is not under '//D:\539707\localbuild\DevBranches\BETA\UCB102\bms102/...'